# Find text and replace paragraph as a style

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, wildcards

I'm working with a large document in Word that was converted from .pdf so any outline formatting was stripped out. I'm looking to run find replace where I'm looking for wildcard "[A-Z]. " and want to replace it with the style for that outline level, but I want to replace for the entire paragraph, not just the characters from the wildcard selection. What could I add to the replace box besides the style info to achieve that?

Comment: Can you have the regex match the entire paragraph?

Comment: No, I'm looking for outline numbering and letters (e.g. "A. ", "1. ", etc.), but I want the entire paragraph to have the outline style when I select the "replace" button, not just the characters.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. If you’re replacing with a paragraph style (see [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NeAOc.png)), it will apply to the entire paragraph, even if you have selected only a couple of characters. At least, it works in Word 2013, and it has worked for several years. Are you using a *really, **really** old* version of Word?

Comment: Interesting, the first time I tried, it didn't work.  Please post your comment as an answer and I'll give you credit.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I didn't get notified of your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to accomplish,
you don’t need to select the entire paragraph, or even the paragraph mark (¶). 
Just search for the text that distinguishes the paragraphs you’re looking for
(e.g., capital letter, period, space)
and set the “Replace with” to be a paragraph style:

[image: Find text, Replace with style]

It will automatically apply to the entire paragraph.

Comment: Karen927: It occurred to me that capital-period-space isn't really a good enough regular expression to match section titles (and only section titles).  For example, it will match an acronym at the end of a sentence ("Anne went to MIT. Bob didn't go to college.")  But I assume you know the actual content of your document well enough to know what will work.

Comment: Also, you might want to avoid using the words “above” and “below” to refer to answers (as you did in your comment on the other answer).  If a user selects the “active” or “votes” sort order for answers, then their relative positions will vary over time.  Even with “oldest” (i.e., chronological) order, an “accepted” answer will move to the top.  (Speaking of which, you *do* know about “accepting” an answer, don’t you?  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

When you're using wildcards, ^13 is the special character used to represent a paragraph mark. (This page from Microsoft lists the special characters that can be used with a wildcard search: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176776)

Comment: The answer above should work. If the paragraphs you want to reformat are all formatted uniquely, wildcards may not even be required. Just format the paragraph mark in the "Replace with" field in the style you want for the parageaph text that follows. In my experience, PDFs containing leading between paragraphs often appear as two line spaces when converted to DOCX (depending on the source of the PDF). If that's the case, just search for two paragraph marks and replace them with one such mark (formatted to the desired style).

Comment: You completely misunderstood what my question was. See Scott's answer below.